# is it possible to make redis return long value when uing range command

Tags: redis

Now my article id stored as long in PostgreSQL, when I cached the id into redis like this:

```
 articleIds = redisTemplate.opsForList().range(cachedArticleType,start,end);
```

to my suprise the return list was Integer value, so I have to convert it to long like this:

```
List<Long> articleLongIds = articleIds.stream()
                    .mapToLong(item->Long.parseLong(item.toString()))
                    .boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

is it possible to auto get long value and did not need the convert step?Now I tried to define the redistemplate like this:

```
private final RedisTemplate<String,Long> redisLongTemplate;
```

then tried to get id like this(I have changed the data structure to ZSet but I think it is seem problem):

```
Set<Long> articleIds = redisLongTemplate.opsForZSet().reverseRangeByScore(cachedArticleType, 0, max, offset, count);
```

but get the result set also integer:

[image]

I finnaly found is the deseriable problem:

```
@Bean(name = "redisLongTemplate")
    RedisTemplate<String, Long> redisTemplateLong(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Long> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        template.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer serializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(Long.class);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
        serializer.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        template.setValueSerializer(serializer);
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(serializer);
        template.setHashValueSerializer(serializer);
        template.afterPropertiesSet();
        return template;
    }
```

define Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer using Long class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're using String as a value in the Redis template if you define a template as `RedisTemplate<String, Long>` then it should work out of the box.

```
RedisTemplate<String, Long> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
Long data = 19000L;
redisTemplate.opsForList().rightPush("test_long_l", data);
redisTemplate.opsForList().rightPush("test_long_l", data + 1);
redisTemplate.opsForList().rightPush("test_long_l", data + 2);
List<Long> data = redisTemplate.opsForList().range("test_long_l", 0, -1);

System.out.println(data);
```

Comment: I tried your way it seems not work @sonus21